# Midpoints of matrix rows depending on certain conditions Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A with size 10x100 as shown below. What I want to do is:

1. I'll work row by row in which for each row I'll check the data of
   each coloumn in this row
2. Let's say I'm now in the first col cell in the first row. I'll check if the value is zero I'll move to the next col, and so on till I found a col having a non-zero value and save its col number e.g. col 3 "this means that col 1&2 were zeros"
3. Now I'm in the first non zero col in row1, I'll move to the next col till I find a col with zero value. I'll fetch the col just before this zero one which must be a non-zero one and save it. e.g col 7 "this means that col4&5&6 are non-zeros and col8 is zero"
4. Now I want to save the median middle col between this two columns e.g col3 and col7 then the middle col is col5 so I'll save the index row1_col5. if there are two middle values then any of them is fine.
5. I'll then move to the next col till I find a non-zero col "do the
   same steps from 2-->5" till the first row is finished.
6. Move to the next row and start over again from step 2-->5.
7. There are two rules: -The first one is that I'll get the middle index of non-zero consecutive values only if there is a minimum of 3 non-zero consecutive values, if there are two non-zero consecutive value then the middle will not be calculated -The second one is that if the number of zero consecutive values are less than 3 then they will be ignored and will be considered as non-zero values. e.g in the below example the first row middle values are col5 and col11. In row2 col5 is counted, while no cols in row3 satisfy this conditions , and in row4 col6 or col7 will be counted.
8. After finishing all the rows want to have a vector or array holding the positions of all the middle indexes e.g row1_col5 row1_col17 row2_col_10 and so on.

example:

```
A = [ 0 0 0 2 4 1 0 0 0 1 3 2;
      0 0 0 5 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1;
      0 3 4 1 0 3 1 2 0 0 1 3;
      0 0 0 0 1 3 4 5 0 0 0 0];
```

for the first row the middle value will be 5 and 11 and so on
So if anyone could please advise how can I do this with least processing as this can be done using loops but if there is more efficient way of doing it? Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: Do you also want to count cases where there's a non-zero value with a zero on either side?

Comment: @nkjt If you mean by this that the first or last col are non-zero, then yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you have clarified your question (again...) here is a solution (still using a for loop...). It includes "rule 7" - excluding runs of fewer than three elements; it also includes the second part of that rule - runs of fewer than three zeros don't count as zero.  The new code looks like this:

```
A = [ 0 0 0 2 4 1 0 0 0 1 3 2;
      0 0 0 5 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1;
      0 3 4 1 0 3 1 2 0 0 1 3;
      0 0 0 0 1 3 4 5 0 0 0 0];

 retVal = cell(1, size(A, 1));
 for ri = 1:size(A,1)
     temp = [1 0 0 0 A(ri,:) 0 0 0 1]; % pad ends with 3 zeros + 1
                                       % so that is always a "good run"
     isz = (temp == 0); % find zeros - pad "short runs of 0" with ones
     diffIsZ = diff(isz);
     f = find(diffIsZ == 1);     
     l = find(diffIsZ == -1);
     shortRun = find((l-f)<3); % these are the zeros that need eliminating

     for ii = 1:numel(shortRun)
         temp(f(shortRun(ii))+1:l(shortRun(ii))) = 1;
     end

     % now take the modified row:
     nz = (temp(4:end-3)~=0);
     dnz = diff(nz); % find first and last nonzero elements
     f = find(dnz==1); 
     l = find(dnz==-1);
     middleValue = floor((f + l)/2);
     rule7 = find((l - f) > 2);
     retVal{ri} = middleValue(rule7);
 end
```

You have to use a cell array for the return value since you don't know how many elements will be returned per row (per your updated requirement).

The code above returns the following cell array:

```
{[5 11], [6], [7], [7]}
```

I appear still not to understand your "rule 7", because you say that "no columns in row 3 satisfy this condition". But it seems to me that once we eliminate the short runs of zeros, it does. Unless I misinterpret how you want to treat a run of non-zero numbers that goes right to the edge (I assume that's OK - which is why you return `11` as a valid column in row 1; so why wouldn't you return `7` for row 3??)

Comment: Your solution looks very good. However, that `fl` is undefined. Probably `nz`?

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for your answer, but still this is not working with multiple values in one row, I've tried A = [ 0 0 2 4 1 0 1 3 2 0;
      0 3 5 5 1 0 0 2 2 0;
      0 3 4 1 0 3 1 2 0 0;
      0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0];
Also I've added two conditions in step 7 so if it is possible I'm asking if you could please check it?

Comment: Use the solution by @Floris, which is great. You only have to replace "fl" by "dnz" in the two lines that contain "find"

Comment: Oh -- new conditions in step 7. You seem to be complicating things little by little :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I've edited it but still getting one middle value per row

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm sorry for that :) and I really appreciate your kind assistance

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks for pointing out the inconsistency in my variable names. I initially had `fl`, didn't like it and started changing to `dnz` for `difference non zero` but didn't carry it forward.

Comment: @Floris thank you very much for your answer!  I've added two conditions in step 7 , I'm asking if you could check it please?

Comment: @Floris Yes, that's what I thought. Happens a lot :-)

Comment: @luismendo I saw you attempted to make the edit, and it was rejected by peer reviewers. But your edit was correct. I have now fixed it - and thanks.

Comment: @Floris You're welcome. And your solution, with the plus/minus 1, is great :-)

Comment: @user1460166 I now see there is a "second part to rule 7", but I don't understand your interpretation of your own rule. "Count fewer than 3 consecutive zeros as non-zero" I get, but then what value do you expect to return from row 3? I would think it would be `5` (which happens to be a zero but it's the middle of the run `3 4 1 0 3 1 2`) - and why is only one value returned from row 1? There are three zeros between the first and second run - and I thought we could consider the "end of the rows" to have zeros next to them (per your comment). Makes no sense at all. Please clarify more.

Comment: @Floris Thanks for your comment. Sorry, I did a mistake with row1 and I've updated the question to include both col_5 and col_11. Regarding col_3, it will be the middle which is col_6 because after the 2 there is two zeros "not three" so they will be counted as non-zero values, so the middle will be col_6. Please let me know if any more clarification is needed. Many Thanks

Comment: Then can you confirm that my current solution does everything you ask? The last paragraph in your question still says "for the first row the middle value will be 4 and 8" - I think you want that to say "5 and 11" as in the earlier text...

Comment: @Floris yes its 5 & 11 Sorry I've updated the one part and forgot to update the second one, now its updated. Its working fine but for row_3  the middle value should be col_6 because the number of concecutive zeros in this row are less than 3 so they will be counted as non-zero elements

Comment: @Floris I'm wondering if you got the chance to check my previous comment?

Comment: I did - and I wrote a solution. I will upload it later today (different computer). Basic approach: copy row into temporary variable, find "runs of < 3 zeros" (almost the opposite of what I do above), set them to ones, then use algorithm above to find "runs of non-zeros" and find their middle. Hope to have chance to upload working code this evening.

Comment: @Floris I'm asking if you could please check the update, and please let me know if anything needs more clarification. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend that you write a new question with a link posted here. It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do -the numbers in your row `A` in the update don't seem to match the text you use to describe it. In general, if you want the vectors `l` and `f` to be the same length, you have to make sure there are equal numbers of "start sequence" and "end sequence" points - which I did in my answer by "padding" the ends as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sizeA = size(A);
N = sizeA(1);
D = diff([zeros(1, N); (A.' ~= 0); zeros(1,N)]) ~= 0;
[a b] = find(D ~= 0);

c = reshape(a, 2, []);
midRow = floor(sum(c)/2);
midCol = b(1:2:length(b))
```

After this, midRow and midCol contain the indices of your centroids (e.g. midRow(1) = 1, midCol(1) = 4 for the example matrix you gave above.

Comment: No for loops required. Also the D ~= 0 in the 4th line of code is redundant. Also, midRow and midCol have their logical names swapped.

Comment: its giving this error "Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent."

Comment: See my edit (sizeA(1) instead of sizeA(2)). Also, I just saw your requirement #7 and this doesn't fulfill it. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks alot! this fix it, I've added two conditions in step 7 , I'm asking if you could please check it

Comment: I'm wondering if you got the chance to check my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a `for` loop:

```
A = [ 0 0 1 1 1 0 1;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
      0 1 1 1 1 0 0;
      0 1 1 1 0 1 1;
      0 0 0 0 1 0 0]; % data

sol = repmat(NaN,size(A,1),1);
for row = 1:size(A,1)
  [aux_row aux_col aux_val] = find(A(row,:));
  if ~isempty(aux_col)
    sol(row) = aux_col(1) + floor((find(diff([aux_col 0])~=1,1)-1)/2);
    % the final 0 is necessary in case the row of A ends with ones
    % you can use either "floor" or "ceil"
  end
end

disp(sol)
```

Try it and see if it does what you want. I hope the code is clear; if not, tell me

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although the thing is that it only works one time per row getting only one middle value, but what I want is to detect as many middle values as possible per row. So for example if A = [ 0 0 2 4 1 0 1 3 2 0;
      0 3 5 5 1 0 0 2 2 0;
      0 3 4 1 0 3 1 2 0 0;
      0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]; then in the first row there are two middle values 4 and 3.

Comment: I tried doing this without for loops for a bit and convinced myself it would get very messy. This looks like the right approach - although I don't like your way of initializing `sol` very much. And it's not clear what happens if there is a row of zeros. I believe `aux_row` will be empty and the code will throw an error. Add a `try-catch` around the line where you assign `sol(row)`, or test for `[]`?

Comment: @user1460166 that was clearly NOT how you phrased your question. You said "find a value, then move to the next row." Please update the question according to your actual requirement!

Comment: @Floris thanks for your comments, in step5 I said that I'll continue getting the other middle values till the row is finished

Comment: @Luis Mendo sorry in my first comment I meant in the first row there are two middle values 4 and 8

Comment: @user1460166 I see. It's trickier if there are several runs per row

Comment: @floris You're right about the row of zeros. I have corrected it (`if ~isempty...`). How is it best to initialize `sol`?

Comment: @LuisMendo - since you don't know the dimensions of the return value per row I think a cell array is better...